# What is the difference in usage between "sports meet" and "sports meeting"?

Tags: word-usage

In the past I had only heard the term "sports meet" and I assume it is American English. Recently, though, I have heard some English language learners call it "sports meeting." Is that British English?

Comment: In the USA it's called a "meet". Elsewhere, I understand it's called a "meeting" or a "tournament" or a number of other names. Sports is very local.

Comment: In the US a "sports meeting" would be ambiguous, and would probably be more likely to be interpreted as a meeting (as in the school cafeteria) whose subject is sports.

Answer (score 2):

In the US it's ***meet***:

> **meet**
>
> noun
>
> 1
>
> b :  **a sports meeting** consisting of competitive events especially in
>   track and field, swimming, or gymnastics contested by individuals and
>   often by relay or other teams
>
> c :  **a sports contest** of any of various other kinds
>
> *basketball meet*
>
> *trapshooters' meet*
>
> *sports car meet*
>
> d :  a **festival or competition** of any of various other kinds
>
> *singing meet*
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

A sorts meeting could be a meeting (as in discussion) about sports. Sports meet is kind of a festival having number of sporting events. As an example, inter house sports meet is an annual festival schools may have.

Answer (score -2):

> Sports meet

seems like slang or even outright poor English to me. Looking for a definition, the term simply doesn't exist.

> Sports meeting

is the correct way to say it.

> sports meeting - a meeting at which a number of athletic contests are held

Comment: Though I've also had trouble finding it online, I've been in sports for the past 20 years, and every one of them (American) has called them a "sports meet". I'd never even heard the term "sports meeting" until just now.

Comment: *meet*: 2 An organized event at which a number of races or other athletic contests are held: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meet)